# How do global and static variables work together in C?

Tags: c, static, global-variables

I have to determine the output of this program (without running it on the computer). I am pretty unsure on how the global and static variables work together.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int d);

int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;

int main()
{
    int a = 5, c = 6;
    f(a);
    f(b);
    f(c);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d);
    return 0;
}

void f(int d)
{
    static int a = 0;
    a = a + 7;
    b = a + d;
    c++;
    d--;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d);
}
```

Comment: 1) Google for static variable in a function, 2) go through the program step by step.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "static" mean in a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program)

Comment: There are no global variables in C.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable defintions always "hide" global variables with the same name. An inner scope always takes precedence over an outer one. Some compilers also produce warning when a variable "shadows" another one.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest visible binding in scope hides all the further ones. So in `main` all the names refer to the local variables, and in `f` only `a` is the local one (albeit static, that's immaterial), `d` refers to the function parameter, and `b` and `c` refer to the global ones.

You can unhide farther-away names to a limited extend with the `extern` keyword, but given enough local scopes you can always create and hide variables that you can never see from somewhere deeper.

Answer (score 0):

If two variables are declared with the same identifier, the accesses refer to the one with the smallest scope.

> > #### C11 (n1570), § 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers
> >
> > If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
> >     space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end
> >     strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the
> >     identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
> >     scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.